# Faltan varias cadenas en la página de "/review"

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones, agregar-a-transifex

Visitando la nueva página de [/review](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review) encontré que tiene un nuevo diseño. Como suele pasar cuando actualizan una página, algunos textos están en inglés.

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así que procedí a hacer mi búsqueda en [traducir.win](https://traducir.win/) con estos parámetros:

- **Meta reviews** -> https://traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Meta%20reviews
- **Choose task to get started** -> https://traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Choose%20a%20task%20to%20get%20started
- **Recent reviews** -> https://traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Recent%20reviews

Pero la búsqueda no tuvo éxito

¿Podríamos agregar estas cadenas a Transifex?

Comment: arreglado en https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322030/238921

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respuesta de [Adam Lear ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/adam-lear) en el [reporte](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322030/384394) de [gbianchi](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) en meta.se

> Sorry about that. Looks like the string export to Transifex failed on our last production build. We kicked off another export, and the strings should be there now.
>
> Thanks for the report!

---

**Traducción**

> Lo siento por eso. Parece que la exportación de cadenas a Transifex falló en nuestra última build de producción. Hicimos otra exportación, y las cadenas deberían estar ahí ahora.
>
> ¡Gracias por el reporte!